# Selenium - iframe headache - unable to solve

Tags: python, python-2.7, iframe, selenium

I have been banging my head against the wall with this for long enough that I am okay to turn here at this point.

I have a page with iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" tabindex="0" src="" title="Rich text editor, listing_description" aria-describedby="cke_18" style="width:100%;height:100%">
```

When I get by xpath using:
         `'//*[@aria-describedby="cke_18"]'`

I get a web element where:

```
>>> elem
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x104327b50>
>>> elem.id
u'{3dfc8264-71bc-c948-882a-acd6a8b93ab5}'
>>> elem.is_displayed
<bound method WebElement.is_displayed of <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x104327b50>>
```

Now, when I try to extract to put information in this iframe, I get something along the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 560, in debugfile
    debugger.run("runfile(%r, args=%r, wdir=%r)" % (filename, args, wdir))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/jasonmellone/Documents/PythonProjects/nakedApts.py", line 88, in <module>
    a = elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//*")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 201, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 377, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/8x/0msd5dd13l9453ff9739rj7w0000gn/T/tmpmH4ARe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8905)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElement (file:///var/folders/8x/0msd5dd13l9453ff9739rj7w0000gn/T/tmpmH4ARe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8917)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/8x/0msd5dd13l9453ff9739rj7w0000gn/T/tmpmH4ARe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10884)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/8x/0msd5dd13l9453ff9739rj7w0000gn/T/tmpmH4ARe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10889)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/8x/0msd5dd13l9453ff9739rj7w0000gn/T/tmpmH4ARe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)`

Now, I, not being a selenium developer, have no idea what this means.

When I run the following code:

```
   elem = Helper.getElementByxPath(mydriver,'//*[@aria-describedby="cke_18"]',"ABC"); 
   mydriver.switch_to_frame(elem);
```

The above runs where `Helper.getElementByxPath` is:

```
    def getElementByxPath(mydriver,xPath,valueString):

        try:

            a = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath);
            a.send_keys(valueString);
            return a;
        except:
            print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0];
            return 0;

   a = elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//*")
```

Giving me the following:

```
>>> elem.id

 u'{8be4819b-f828-534a-9eb2-5b791f42b99a}'
```

And the following statement:

```
  a = elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//*")
```

Gives me another huge error.

The frustrating part to me is the following:

1. I don't need to get information out of the embedded input in the iframe, I just want to sendkeys.
2. I am **HAPPY** to just "Keys.TAB" until I reach the proper box, and Cursor.location.element.send_keys (pseudo code).
3. I just want to type text on the page as the CURSOR IS ALREADY IN THE RIGHT PLACE (can't i just do this easily?)

My goal is to just send keys here, not to do anything deeper, and I cannot seem to solve this problem without getting something like the above issue.

Is there a way to solve this? I am quite defeated and hope someone has an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: the only important part of the stacktrace is ` u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*"}' ; Stacktrace:`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes but what do I do with that?

Comment: have you used firebug or something similar to inspect the element to see if you are actually getting the correct xpath for what you want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sure but how do you mean? The iframe has no "name" but the element seems proper in the way I am accessing it. I have firebug so please let me know if i am missing something here.

Comment: Seems you are dealing with CKEditor. `aria-describedby="cke_18"` is not the right thing to use. I'd suggest use something like `.//iframe[@title='Rich text editor, listing_description']` if unique. (But the best would be to add unique class names). For your reference, here's an article you might have a look at: [Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/). Basically, you can just call editor's native JavaScript API instead of dealing with iframes.

Comment: hey Yi, had no idea about ckeditor, but this is exactly the problem I am facing. could we move this off SO into email? My email is in my profile. I can send you the exact page I am having the issue with and maybe you could direct me a bit more specifically?

Comment: SOLVED IT I COULD HUG YOU

Comment: @jasonm: Sorry, just saw your comments. Glad you have it solved. You might consider adding an answer below and accept your own answer, so that other people can see how to solve it in the future. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my specific issue is the following snippet of code:

```
            elem = Helper.getElementByxPath(mydriver,".//iframe[@title='theTitleOfMyIframe']","ABC"); 
            mydriver.switch_to_frame(elem);
            elem2 = Helper.getElementByxPath(mydriver,"//body[@contentEditable='true']","ABC");
```

Where my xpath function is:

```
            def getElementByxPath(mydriver,xPath,valueString):

                try:

                    a = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath);
                    a.send_keys(valueString);
                    return a;
                except:
                    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0];
                    return 0;
```

Once you are sure you have your ckeditor in scope you should be able to run the following:

```
  mydriver.execute_script(str("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'test'"), elem2)
```

And it should work as you anticipate! Hope this helps others save time!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can only access elements in the current frame.  You can switch to a deeper frame like this:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(IDENTIFIER)
```

Where IDENTIFIER is:
 - The name of the frame
 - A webelement reference to the frame
 - The numeric index of the frame

API reference here:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

When you finish in the `iframe`, you can switch to the top level with the following:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: please see above. I understand your point but it is not giving me the desired end result.